# Witr salat with isha and tahajud

Tags: salat, tahajjud

If I performed witr salah during isha prayer, can or do I need to perform witr salah with tahajut prayer  as I read tahajut prayer should be odd 9 or 11 rakha.

Answer (score 1):

walecum assalam

Isha prayer is one of the Fard prayers and you have to pray witr with isha only. Tahajjud has no direct connection with Witr prayer. So if you prayed Witr with isha, thats all you need to do. **you dont need to pray witr with tahajjud prayer again**.

But in case you're sure that you would pray Tahajjud prayer, you can pray witr at the end of the Tahajjud prayer(but its not fard), and thereby making it odd.

And yes, according to hadith, witr can be 1 or 3 or odd numbers.

Here are some hadith to cover this issue:

> Ali (bin Abu Talib) (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Witr
>   prayer is not obligatory as the prescribed Salat (prayers), but the
>   Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) observed it as his
>   regular practice (Sunnah). He (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) said,
>   "Allah is Witr (single, odd) and loves what is Witr. So perform Witr
>   prayer. O followers of Qur'an, observe Witr (prayer).'' [At-Tirmidhi
>   and Abu Dawud].
>
> `Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) reported: The Messenger of
>   Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) observed Witr prayer in every
>   part of night at the beginning, middle and at the last part. He
>   (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam), however, would finish his Witr prayer
>   before dawn. [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].