# Should I pray the witr after Tahajjud prayer?

Tags: tahajjud, witr

Assalamu alaikum,

I'm confused about the fact of witr and tahajjud prayer, as said witr is to lock up a day's prayers, should I perform it affter tahajjud prayer? (If I perform the tahajjud prayer at the last part of the night)

I read this here:

> And in many narrations, Our Prophet (pbuh) commands to perform the witr prayer as the last prayer of the night (Buhari, Witr; Muslim, 751...) or just before the sunnah prayer of the fajr salath (Tirmidi, 467; Ebu Davud, 1436...), and for those who have a fear of not being able to wake up at night, to perform it after the isha salath (Muslim, 755). In that case, it is much more virtuous for those who do not have a fear of not being able to wake up, to have a sleep after the isha salath and to wake up in a certain time of the night then to perform the tahajjud prayer, and after that the witr salath and finally to perform the sunnah salath of the fajr prayer. (Source: http://www.questionsonislam.com/article/tahajjud-prayer-night-prayer)

Please enlighten me.

Jazakallah Khaier.

Comment: These seem to be the same or relevant questions  http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/is-it-okay-to-perform-tahajjud-after-witir?noredirect=1&lq=1 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/witr-salat-with-isha-and-tahajud?rq=1

Comment: @Sassir, okay, but I do want to pray the tahajjud at the end of the night, can I pray witr after that time? I never knew this before

Comment: It is also said somewhere that witr prayer should be performed before sleeping, so if I want to pray it after tahajjud, then how can I pray witr before sleeping?

Comment: Well honestly the question can widely be answered: As you can pray witr before tahajjud or night prayer if you plan to sleep and are afraid you won't wake up. On the other hand you still can pray witr qada'/qaza' if you slept and missed the night prayer AFAIK, but I don't recall the time limit for that. And you can pray it after the night prayer this seems to have back up in hadith as it is said one should let the last prayer of the night be a witr. But as it seems the other way was also accepted and practiced.

Comment: The only thing i could say is you should perform it or plan to perform it, before the time for fajr. So you can either go on the safe side and pray it before sleeping after 'isha' prayer or stop tahajjud if you fear to miss witr once the fajr time comes close and perform it then. For the possibility of qaza' as stated by Sassir I'm not sure about the madhab opinions.

Comment: then its okay if I take a deep or light sleep or nap, then wake up for tahajjud and then pray witr. I meant, it wont be a problem if I pray the witr after having sleep?

Comment: @Sassir.........

Comment: @Medi1Saif...........

Comment: No that's perfectly fine. Tahajjud is also defined as night prayer after a nap.

Comment: This question different from http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/is-it-okay-to-perform-tahajjud-after-witir sequences are different. Totally different questions.

Comment: and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/witr-salat-with-isha-and-tahajud is have some partial answer for tihs question but OPs are asking different things. It was like I am asking for apple but you gave a little more information for orange also.